# I want to sync my SQL data to elasticsearch asynchronously in .NET for indexing data so that I can search my data quickly

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

Here is the scenario
I have a .NET application with huge amount of user data and one of the use-case is to search for a particular user. Currently the search is done using SQL queries which takes too much time to give results. So I planned to move it to elastic search. So whenever a new user registers I want to index it in elasticsearch asynchronously as a background-process so that it does not interfere with current application.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server:

[image: CDC]

You can get new and updated records from a given table and decide what to do with it (send to Elastic, for example).